# Am trying to move files from a folder to desktop in Python. But am getting error

Tags: python-2.7, shutil

Am trying to move files from a folder to desktop in Python. But am getting error.
Below is my code and error:

```
import shutil
import os
source_dir = 'C:\Users\dupakunt\Desktop\Testdir'
os.makedirs(source_dir)
os.chdir(source_dir)
open("newfile1.txt", "w")
open("newfile2.txt", "w")
target = 'C:\Users\dupakunt\Desktop'
dir_list = os.listdir(source_dir)
for x in source_dir:
    print x
    shutil.move(x,target)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cleanup-undo.py", line 12, in <module>
    shutil.move(x,target)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 302, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 130, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 82, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C'.
```

Answer (score 0):

`source_dir` is the directory name, you want to run through the `dir_list` files in the directory. There are a few other items to attend to

- Backslashes are used to escape non-printable characters in strings. Use raw strings if you want them to be path separators, or use `/` separators which work on linux and windows in python.
- Its confusing to mix `chdir` and absolute paths. I recommend avoiding `chdir` when possible and just use `os.path.join` to make relative paths absolute.
- use `with` clauses. Your code works with cpython, but with some other variants, the files may still be open after the `open` completes.
- When enumerating the directory, filter out subdirectories.

Example

```
import shutil
import os
source_dir = r'C:\Users\dupakunt\Desktop\Testdir'
os.makedirs(source_dir)
with open(os.path.join(source_dir, "newfile1.txt"), "w"):
    pass
with open(os.path.join(source_dir, "newfile2.txt"), "w"):
    pass
target = r'C:\Users\dupakunt\Desktop'
dir_list = os.listdir(source_dir)
for x in dir_list:
    if os.path.isfile(x):
        x = os.path.join(target, x)
        print x
        shutil.move(x,target)
```

Comment: Hi. The modified code is not showing any errors. But, its not moving the files from dir to desktop. My python version is 2.7 and am running this in windows 7 machine.

Comment: my bad... I forgot to build the destination path.

Comment: its same. No errors, but its not moving the files to desktop from folder Testdir

Comment: I realised my mistake. Instead of using for x in source_dir in the program i need to use for x in dir_list which will do the job